# How to pass data from Laravel to Vue.js component v-for

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-for

How to pass data from Laravel to Vue.js component v-for ?

I have tried the code below:

```
<my-component
    v-for="(event, eventIndex) in {{ $data['events'] }}">
</my-component>
```

But it returns:

> component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys.

Comment: you sure you want to have multiple `my-component` or you want a `v-for` inside this component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use curly braces syntax in bindings.

```
<my-component v-for="(event, eventIndex) in events" />
```

`events` array needs to be defined in your vm's data function:

```
data() {
  return {
    events: [] // initialize as an empty array if you fetch the data async
  }
}
```

If you want to fetch your event data asynchronously when the page loads, put the ajax call inside the `created()` hook of your vm:

```
created() {
  $.ajax({ method: 'get', url: 'your/api/to/get/events' })
    then((response)=> {this.events = response.data})
}
```

To solve the warning message Vue is showing you, add a `:key="event.id"` (if your events have an `id` property, otherwise any other unique property):

```
<my-component v-for="(event, eventIndex) in events" :key="event.id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says that you should use `:key` binding:

> component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys.

```
    <my-component
        v-for="(event, eventIndex) in {{ $data['events'] }}" :key="eventIndex">
         <!-- You can bind key to unique key, :key="event.id" -->
         <!-- However, it's perfectly good to use :key="eventIndex" -->
    </my-component>
```

From a resource: [v2.2.0 release](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.2.0)

> When using v-for with a component, a key is now required. You will likely see a bunch of "soft warnings" when you upgrade, but this does not affect the current behavior of your app.

Comment: Adding the `eventIndex` as a key makes no sense other than getting rid of the warning.

Comment: The Vue message says "should", not "needs to".

Comment: @connexo while using `v-for` inside a component you must provide a `:key`

Comment: Why not read the docs you're linking? You don't have to. *It is **recommended** to provide a key with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.*

Comment: When you use `v-for` inside a div you can omit `:key` but it's a required while using component. I have read somewhere, trying to find the source.

Comment: You are probably referring to the API docs: *Children of the same common parent must have **unique keys**. Duplicate keys will cause render errors.* This only refers to keys having to be unique. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key